# Is the not operator (!) behaving differently in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, not-operator

The following values are considered "falsy" in JavaScript:

- false
- 0
- ''
- ""
- null
- undefined
- NaN

Does TypeScript handle the not operator (!) differently or is it the same?

Comment: TypeScript does have extensive documentation, including operator behavior.. people took time to create and maintain such.. for you included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the [design goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) of Typescript is:

> Preserve runtime behavior of all JavaScript code.

This means that ALL Javascript code will behave the same in Typescript code. No exceptions. You might get extra semantic errors, but if you ignore those the behavior is still the same.

So if you ever wonder if an operator such as `!` behaves differently in TS, the answer will always be no

Comment: Devil’s Advocate: If the == operator was applied to TypeScript-specific code or a TypeScript-specific context (that is, code that is not ever valid in a plain JavaScript context)..

Comment: @user2864740 You might get extra semantic errors in TS, but if you ignores those (and you can ignore TS errors and still get TSC to output the JS code) the code behaves the same at runtime as it would in JS.

Comment: @user2864740 or are you referring to TS specific things such as type operators.. Those are in a different domain and actually have no runtime behavior .. so it's hard to compare with those ..

Comment: The Devil’s argument is that == *could* be transpiled in such a way that it does not strictly violate the quote (because not all valid TS is valid JS). However, volation of such core guidelines would is generally surprising. Documentation specific about the == operator in TS would eliminate grounds for such a pedantic argument.

Comment: @user2864740 I think that particular guidline is core to the usability of TS. I have seen it cited several times as reasons not to to certain features. I don't think there will ever be a good enough reason to make code have a different runtime behavior in TS vs JS. One of the selling points of TS is an easy migation from JS. What kind of migration would it be if parts of your codebase behave differently at runtime in TS vs JS. So even if in principle `==` could behave differently, you can take it to the bank it will not

Answer (score 3):

The emitted JavaScript will, by definition, work the same as JavaScript.

As for what types the compiler recognizes as [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) at design time, the short answer is "everything except `NaN`":

```
const f0 = !false  // true
const f1 = !0; // true
const f2 = !0n; // true
const f3 = !""; // true
const f4 = !null; // true
const f5 = !undefined; // true
const f6 = !NaN; // boolean (no NaN type in TypeScript)
```

Right now TypeScript doesn't have a [numeric literal type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) corresponding to `NaN`; it's only seen as type `number`.  And since a `number` can be either truthy or falsy, the type of `!NaN` is just `boolean`.  There is an open [suggestion, microsoft/TypeScript#28682](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28682) to introduce numeric literals for `NaN` (and for `Infinity` and `-Infinity`) but I don't know if that will ever be addressed.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=99&jsx=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgBhgXhgQjgQwDYQKYwwD0RMUATgK54BQokscAjCuggNzGkXV3jTwATKzQIwnEmSq16AuAGYRAIiUTu0vg3gAWEWErZsaqb1mMArCMpgAJnjgBLMHhvGeM-owBsIgHKZfYwAjEBBsPEwwGAAKMBAYf18yAE8ABwInGAAVNLwAZWByB1SoAEoaCpggA)

Answer (score 1):

**TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript.**

Typescript only adds additional features to JavaScript.
It does not negate any feature or functionality of JavaScript.

What is false in JavaScript is false in TypeScript also.
What is true in JavaScript is also true in TypeScript.